# Deleting everything except newest files

Tags: linux, filesystems

Lets say I have a directory `ḟoo/` which contains a lot of files in some sort of directory structure. I need to keep some of them, but not all of it.

Is there a way to (in place) delete all of them except (say) 500 newest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do this task regularly, and I use variants of the following. It is a pipeline combining various simple tools: Find all files, prepend the file modification time, sort, remove the file modification time, display all lines except the 500 first, and remove them:

```
find foo/ -type f | perl -wple 'printf "%12u ", (stat)[9]' | \
    sort -r | cut -c14- | tail -n +501 | \
    while read file; do rm -f -- "$file"; done
```

A few comments:

- If you are using “bash”, you ought to use “read -r file”, not just “read file”.
- Using “perl” to remove the files is faster (and also handles “weird” characters in the file names better than the while-loop does, unless you are using “read -r file”):

  ```
  ... | tail -n +501 | perl -wnle 'unlink() or warn "$_: unlink failed: $!\n"'
  ```
- Some versions of “tail” do not support the “-n” option, so you must use “tail +501”. A portable way to skip the 500 first lines is

  ```
   ... | perl -wnle 'print if $. > 500' | ...
  ```
- It won’t work if your file names contain newlines.
- It is does not require GNU find.

Combining the above gives you:

```
find foo/ -type f | perl -wple 'printf "%12u ", (stat)[9]' | \
    sort -r | cut -c14- | perl -wnle 'print if $. > 500' | \
    perl -wnle 'unlink() or warn "$_: unlink failed: $!\n"'
```

Comment: I would be careful with `rm -f` though.

Comment: Works like a charm! This should be available as an alias with $path and $count params. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the "500 newest", but with find you can delete stuff that's old than X minutes/days. Example for file and older than 2 days:

```
find foo/ -mtime +2 -a -type f -exec rm -fv \{\} \;
```

Test first with:

```
find foo/ -mtime +2 -a -type f -exec ls -al \{\} \;
```

Mind the backslashes and the space before "\;". See the find man page for more info.

Comment: The “(say) 500 newest” is the essence here, so I don’t see how this answers the original question.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it in Python 3. which should also work for other OSs.  After testing this, make sure to uncomment the line that actually removes the files.

```
import os,os.path
from collections import defaultdict

FILES_TO_KEEP = 500
ROOT_PATH = r'/tmp/'

tree = defaultdict(list)

# create a dictionary containing file names with their date as the key
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT_PATH):
    for name in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root,name)
        fdate = os.path.getmtime( fname )
        tree[fdate].append(fname)

# sort this dictionary by date
# locate where the newer files (that you want to keep) end
count = 0
inorder = sorted(tree.keys(),reverse=True)
for key in inorder:
    count += len(tree[key])
    if count >= FILES_TO_KEEP:
        last_key = key
        break

# now you know where the newer files end, older files begin within the dict
# act accordingly
for key in inorder:
    if key < last_key:
        for f in tree[key]:
            print("remove ", f)
            # uncomment this next line to actually remove files
            #os.remove(f)
    else:
        for f in tree[key]:
            print("keep    ", f)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you could do with keeping files x days/hours old instead of the newest x number, you could do it just with `tmpwatch --ctime 7d`

Answer (score 2):

I think the `-mtime` and `-newer` options of `find` command are useful for you. You can see `man find` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

why not use this simpler code:

```
$ ls -t1 foo/| xargs -d '\n' rm --
```

Comment: How does this remove all files except the 500 most recent files? And how does this handle subdirectories? I think you might have misunderstood the original posting.